# Change to OnRequestEnd behavior in CF9 (was ColdFusion 9 Bug - Can't Reference a Request Variable in OnRequestEnd)

Tags: coldfusion, application.cfc

Here's a weird one. I haven't had any luck finding any information about this on Google, so I'm wondering if any of you have seen this before?

I've got a CFC in the request scope and then in the onRequestEnd event I grab that CFC out of the request scope and do some end-of-request stuff with it. The problem is I can't reference the variable in my onRequestEnd event because it produces an error that says it's not defined in the scope... but here's where it gets really weird and why I KNOW this is a bug (it's not just a suspicion)... If I DUMP the variable, the cfdump tag successfully displays the CFC and all its stuff... and then produces the same "is undefined in scope" error. Here's a screen-capture.

[image: screen capture of request variable bug]

So... anybody seen this before? 'Cause I'm totally stumped. I've already installed the 9.0.1 updater and both of the cumulative hot fixes.

p.s. Yeah, I know it says OnRequestEnd.cfm, but this is actually inside the Application.cfc onRequestEnd method -- it's a legacy from the framework dating back originally to CF5, just go with it. ;P

---

EDIT: Okay, it's gotten weirder... I tried using evaluate() to set it to a local variable, which apparently works, because then I dump the local variable. The dump still works, even though it's on line 2 ***AFTER*** the line on which the error occurred?!!

[image]

---

EDIT 2: EDIT: Here's the code from the Application.cfc that includes the file where the error occurs:

```
<cffunction name="onRequestEnd" access="public" output="true">
    <cfinclude template="OnRequestEnd.cfm">
</cffunction>
```

It appears to have something to do with the combination of the method and the include file.

It still **fails** if I execute the method in the onRequestStart like this:

```
<cffunction name="onRequestStart" access="public" output="true">
    <cfset onRequestEnd() />
</cffunction>
```

But it **works** fine if I include the file in onRequestStart like this.

```
<cffunction name="onRequestStart" access="public" output="true">
    <cfinclude template="OnRequestEnd.cfm">
</cffunction>
```

HOWEVER! There's obviously more to this because I can't create a simple test case. If I create a new project with a very simple application.cfc in it and replicate all these details, it works fine. So there's something else in the framework that's contributing to it beyond just the method names and file names.

And the file name doesn't seem to actually contribute, since it still **fails** in the same way if I change the name of the file like this:

```
<cffunction name="onRequestEnd" access="public" output="true">
    <cfinclude template="reqend.cfm">
</cffunction>
```

---

EDIT 3: Okay it has nothing to do with the file... well it does, but not with the file name... At the bottom of the onRequestEnd.cfm is this code

```
<!--- this seems to help resolve a leaky-memory issue in CF/JRun --->
<cfset structClear(variables) />
<cfset structClear(request) />
<cfabort />
```

If I comment out those StructClear statements, then the error goes away, which told me that it was executing the OnRequestEnd.cfm twice... and I THINK that means that CF9 changed the behavior of the CFABORT tag and it now executes the onRequestEnd event when the tag is used... it didn't in previous versions of cf...

I didn't find documentation of this, but I did find this [blog from Ben Nadel](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2050-Changes-In-CFLocation-OnRequestEnd-Behavior-In-ColdFusion-9-s-Application-cfc.htm) about this behavior with the CFLOCATION tag, so it seems to be more generally about the onRequestEnd event. It seems now in CF9, no matter how a page finishes executing, the onRequestEnd event is executed at the end... That's a change from all the previous versions and so it mucks with code I had created in order to actually cause this to happen on previous versions. Since I was causing execution of the onRequestEnd and then aborting the page early, CF now executes the onRequestEnd, aborts and then executes the onRequestEnd again because of the abort.

Luckily, this fairly simple bit of code at the top of the template seems to fix the problem:

```
<cfif structIsEmpty(request)>
    <cfexit method="exittemplate" />
</cfif>
```

Comment: If you call OnRequestEnd from another function, maybe OnRequestStart, do you get an expected result or the same problem?

Comment: Yeah, that's a good question. It seems to be something to do with the combination of the file and the onRequestEnd method in the Application.cfc. If I call that function from inside onRequestStart, I still get the error, but if I comment out the contents of the onRequestEnd method and put the same cfinclude at the end of the onRequestStart method, then it doesn't throw the error. So that's new information - we're getting closer! Thanks, Dan!

Comment: Do me a favour?  Put the code into the onRequestEnd() event handler, and rename OnRequestEnd.cfm (so it does not get identified by CF as a significant file).  Then put a try/catch around the dump, and in the catch, dump out a structKeyArray() of the request scope.  Post the screen cap of that.  I have no basis for this, but having onRequestEnd() handlers calling OnRequestEnd.cfm handlers seems like something that could potentially cause problems (ie: if there was a weird CF bug).  Also do the same with Application.cfm / onRequestStart(), if you have an Application.cfm file lying around.

Comment: Thanks, Adam! In the process of doing this testing you suggested, I discovered the problem... turns out not to have been what any of us were thinking, it was caused by a change to the onRequestEnd behavior in CF9 that I don't see documented, but that Ben Nadel mentioned in a blog. I'm going to update this question with the answer. I wonder if I should delete this question now?

Comment: Glad you got your problem fixed.  I'd leave the question here as it's important information.  Just post an answer and I guess mark it as such. That bug with `<cfabort>` (which was introduced by design by Adobe in CF9.0.1) is fixed in CF10, btw.

Comment: LOL... Thanks, Adam. I'll answer it in a second... but I thought it was funny that they didn't tell anyone they were adding it in CF9 and then removed it again in CF10. I made 2 comments about it on the LiveDocs for 9, since I didn't see any mention there either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to leave this question here (rather than deleting it) since it may help some other folks, though I found the source of the problem and a workaround while working with some of the comments and it wasn't what we thought. Ben Nadel also [posted a blog about the change to CFABORT](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2221-CFAbort-And-OnRequestEnd-Behavior-In-ColdFusion-8-And-ColdFusion-9.htm) a while ago as well... and Adam Cameron tells me that although this change was added by-design in CF9 (without warning anyone apparently, since I saw no mention in the LiveDocs and added 2 comments about it), it was then removed in the (not yet released?) CF10. I think Adam might be in the beta, I'm not sure.

Comment: It's a public beta, mate.  Anyone can get hold of CF10 and give it a spin.